# Why the click with with selenium did not work in new browser but can work in console

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am currently using webdriver.Chrome to crawling data from a flight price searching website. After filling the search character, the click action on the search button did not work. After it finished, I run the click code separately with the same session of webdriver, it actually worked.

The Html code for the search button is

```
<div class="crl_sp_action">
     <button class="btn_search" type="submit" data-track="key=101020008&amp;val=国内搜索">搜&nbsp;索</button>
```

Sorry about the Chinese words in it where 搜索 means search.

The code for finding and clicking the button is

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()
```

After running it, the click button seems not working, but it print "load done".

The whole part of the code is

```
import time
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/tswz/Dropbox/Entertainment/Qunar/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('http://flight.qunar.com')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
from_city=u'杭州(HGH)'
to_city=u'北京(BJS)' 

date = datetime.date.today()
tomorrow = date+datetime.timedelta(days=3)
tomorrow_string = tomorrow.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

driver.find_element_by_name('fromCity').clear()
driver.find_element_by_name('fromCity').send_keys(from_city)
driver.find_element_by_name('toCity').clear()
driver.find_element_by_name('toCity').send_keys(to_city)
driver.find_element_by_name('fromDate').clear()
driver.find_element_by_name('fromDate').send_keys(tomorrow_string)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()

time.sleep(6)
print "load done!"
```

Another question is how to include the class "crl_sp_action" in the xpath as there is another search button in the webpage. Somebody suggested using by css instead of by xpath, so how to do it?

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="crl_sp_action"]/button[@type="submit"]')`

Comment: @Andersson : Thank you. But it seems no right with error message "NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element"

Comment: I copied text from your code.. and the word `submit` contain some weird symbols :) that is why element can not be found. try this one `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="crl_sp_action"]/button[@type="submit"]')`

Comment: hmm... it still contains those symbols when copy line to `Python` shell... Just enter word `submit` manually:)

Comment: Thanks, it did not generate error message. But I still do not understand why the click action do not work. Sometimes it says "Element is not clickable", sometimes it can work when I only run the click code. I have complete the test code. Can you kindly run it? Then you will know what I means. The orange button is the search button in the website.

Comment: I tried, but for some reasons your code really works incorrectly in `Chrome`, but works perfectly in `Firefox`. I advise you to use `Firefox` browser as it more compatible with `Selenium`

Comment: Thank you. It is true that the code works fine with Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

It's a form, therefore use `submit()` instead of a click

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').submit()`